# Implementation of add element method to linked list in java

Tags: java, list

So this is the code

```
void add(String data) {
    Link newLink = new Link(data);
    newLink.next = firstLink;
    firstLink = newLink;
}
```

If we have only one element firstLink.next will point itself i.e firsLink (because of newLink.next = firstLink;) so it will be not null.
and if we have print method like this:

```
void print() {
    Link currentLink = firstLink;
    while (currentLink != null) {
        System.out.println(currentLink.data);
        currentLink = currentLink.next;
    }
}
```

this should be a infinite loop, but in fact its not true when I start it in eclipse.
My question is why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one element, then `firstLink` was null when you added that first element.

That means that your `add()` method goes like this:

```
void add(String data) {
    Link newLink = new Link(data);    // create new link
    newLink.next = firstLink;         // set newLink.next = null
    firstLink = newLink;              // make newLink the first link
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `firstLink` is initialized to `null` at the start of the program, then the first call to `add(data)` will set `firstLink` to a new Link who's `next` is `null`.